# My css is blocking my JQUERY from executing DOM change

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf

I can't get my input text to turn red once the jquery populated span has reached it's width limit.
I am using this input box to fill a fixed width PDF cell, so I formatted the div to the same font, size and weight as will be outputted in the PDF and I know the fixed width of the PDF cell is 226.

Please attached http://jsfiddle.net/q5hdL/6/ fiddle. The text color turns red when my css is commented out, but fails to turn red when uncommented.

P.S. This is my very first fiddle.

JQUERY code (as mentioned above works fine with css commented out)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#custName').keyup(function(){
            var desc = $(this).val();
            var cache = $(this);
            $('#arial12B').html(desc).promise().done(function(){
                if($('#arial12B').width() > 226){
                    cache.css("color", "#ff0000");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML code

```
    <div id="inputSetBottomLeft">
        <input id="custName" name="custName" type="text" class="custInput" value="' . $customerName . '" />
        <div id="custNameHidden">
            <span id="arial12B">Some test text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code

```
    .custInput{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        color:#cccccc;
        width:228px;
        font-size:12px;
        padding:8px 12px;
        border:1px solid #cccccc;
        border-radius:3px;
        -moz-border-radius:3px;
        -webkit-border-radius:3px;
        -o-border-radius:3px;
     }
    .custInput:focus{
        color:#4c4c4c;
        border:1px solid #9ad065;
    }
    #custNameHidden{
        display:block;
        width:226px;
        background-color:#cccccc;
    }
    #arial12B{
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works for me as expected but `.promise().done()` doesn't make sense here. Please clarify it, is jsFiddle not working for you when CSS is uncommented???

Comment: @A. Wolff try uncommenting the css in the fiddle and then it won't work thanks for your time.

Comment: Like i said, it works for me even CSS is uncommented

Comment: huh works for me commented but not uncommented in jsFiddle

Comment: which browser are you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

This will work in all browsers:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5hdL/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#custName').keyup(function () {
        var desc = this.value;
        var cache = $(this);
        $('#arial12B').html(desc);
        if ($('#arial12B').width() > 226) {
            cache.attr("style", "color:#ff0000 !important");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is just weird your fiddle isn't working in any browsers I have tried including IE, FF, CHROME.

Comment: The funny thing is when I pop in a < (less than) sign in the if statement the text changes.

Comment: OK, good question, have done that test and once again no alert, but again if I switch it to < sign then the alert pops up with the width everytime I type a letter and then stops popping up after it reaches 226

Comment: Wolffy, it seems to be some weird problem with my > sign, anyway I gotta run if you think of anything let me know I will be sure to check answered if we get it figured out.

Comment: That's the first time I heard about some weird behaviour like that